# Get html class from other js file

Tags: javascript

So I need to get to the `addToCart` class from another javascript file.
But the `addToCart` isn't in the html, it is in the javascript:

```js
function loadMeals() {
  let i = 0;
  let id = 1;
  let fillMealList = document.querySelector("#fillMealList");
  for (let i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
    let item = meals.find(item => item.id === id);
    fillMealList.innerHTML +=
      "<article>" +
      "<h3>" + item.title + "</h3>" +
      "<figure>" +
      "<img src='images/" + item.img + "'" + ">" +
      "<figcaption>" +
      "Meal by: " + "<span>" + item.cook + "</span>" +
      "</figcaption>" +
      "</figure>" +
      "<div class='info'>" +
      "<p>€ <span>" + item.price + "</span>" + "/pp" + "</p>" +
      "<a href='#' class='addToCart'>Order</a>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</article>";
    id++;
  }
}
```

Now I need to click on "order" with class `addToCart`.
So I did:

```
document.querySelector("#addToCart").addEventListener("click", addOrder);
```

Now I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null; can't access its "addEventListener" property

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: firstly it'd need to be `.addToCart` because "addtoCart" is a _class_, not an _id_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addToCart` is a class so you need to do `.addToCart` instead of `#addToCart`. Change it to

```
document.querySelector(".addToCart");
```

Note that `addEventListener` will work in your case if there is only one element with that class. Otherwise, you need to use `querySelectorAll()` and attach `addEventListener()` function to each of those elements.